# Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
<?php
include("inc/setting.php");
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {
    $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
    $receptor = $_POST["receptor"];
    $emisor = $_POST["emisor"];
    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mensajes (titulo, receptor, emisor, mensaje) VALUES ('$titulo','$receptor','$emisor','$mensaje')") or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<script>alert("El mensaje se envio exitosamente a ' . $_POST["receptor"] . '")</script>';
}
?>
<form name="mp" method="post" action="">
  <p>Tu Nick:<br>
    <input type="text" name="emisor" id="emisor">
  </p>
  <p>Receptor:<br>
    <input type="text" name="receptor" id="receptor">
  </p>
  <p>Título:<br>
    <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo">
  </p>
  <p>Mensaje:<br>
    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
  </p>
</form>
```

**setting.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$nombre_server[1] = 'localhost'; //Servidor al cual nos vamos a conectar.
$nombre_user[2] = 'ets2mp_a'; //Nombre del usuario de la base de datos.
$password[3] = '5349086a'; //Contraseña de la base de datos
$nombre_db[4] = 'ets2mp_site'; //nombre de la base de datos
$rango = $_SESSION["rango"];

$conectar = @mysql_connect($nombre_server[1],$nombre_user[2],$password[3]) or exit('Datos de conexion incorrectos.');
mysql_select_db($nombre_db[4]) or exit('No existe la base de datos.');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$ultima_actividad=time();

if($rango == 1) {
$rango = 'Desactivado';
}    
elseif($rango == 2) {
$rango = 'Activado';
}    
elseif($rango == 3) {
$rango = 'Baneado';
}    
elseif($rango == 4) {
$rango = 'Coordinador';
}    
elseif($rango == 5) {
$rango = 'Administrador';
}  

function limpiar($var)
{

$var = trim($var);
$var = htmlspecialchars($var);
$var = str_replace(chr(160),'',$var);
return $var;
}

function validar_email($email){
$mail_correcto = 0; 
//compruebo unas cosas primeras 
if ((strlen($email) >= 6) && (substr_count($email,"@") == 1) &&            (substr($email,0,1) != "@") && (substr($email,strlen($email)-1,1) != "@"))
{ 
  if ((!strstr($email,"'")) && (!strstr($email,'"')) &&  (!strstr($email,"/")) && (!strstr($email,"/$")) && (!strstr($email," ")))
   {//miro si tiene caracter .
      if (substr_count($email,".")>= 1)
      {//obtengo la terminacion del dominio 
        $term_dom = substr(strrchr ($email, '.'),1); 
        //compruebo que la terminaci?n del dominio sea correcta 
        if (strlen($term_dom)>1 && strlen($term_dom)<5 && (!strstr($term_dom,"@")) )
         {//compruebo que lo de antes del dominio sea correcto 
           $antes_dom = substr($email,0,strlen($email) - strlen($term_dom) - 1); 
           $caracter_ult = substr($antes_dom,strlen($antes_dom)-1,1); 
           if ($caracter_ult != "@" && $caracter_ult != ".")
            { 
              $mail_correcto = 1; 
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
if ($mail_correcto) 
  return 1;
else 
  return 0;
}

function user_login()
{
if(!$_SESSION['id'])
{
    echo ("<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0;url=inicio'>");
    exit;
}
}

?>
```

When trying to use the code I get the aforementioned error, if I remove `}` I get error `T_VARIABLE` so I do not know the source of the error...

I am sending the entire contents of setting.php, no more calls in the main archive files.

Comment: What's inside your `setting.php`?

Comment: Code looks fine, seems problem in `inc/setting.php`

Comment: @Juaqin123 should have included in your post.

Comment: Is there a file and line number in the error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/site/public_html/web/enviarmensaje.php on line 1

Comment: @Juaqin123 - please, if possible, provide the whole code for your enviarmensaje.php

Comment: The complete code is above setting.php

Comment: @Juaqin123 - I run your enviarmensaje.php on my local here. No problem or error.

Comment: Do not know what can be? only those two files are linked and delete the call setting remains the same mistake so is the enviarmensaje.php file, may be the encoding of the file?

Answer (score -2):

Change your query to this

```
INSERT INTO mensajes (titulo, receptor, emisor, mensaje) VALUES ('{$titulo}','{$receptor}','{$emisor}','{$mensaje}')";
```

And What's Inside include("inc/setting.php");

Comment: is there any difference in OP query? and yours?

Comment: @jogesh_pi 
In query as given below. 

INSERT INTO mensajes (titulo, receptor, emisor, mensaje) VALUES ('$titulo','$receptor','$emisor','$mensaje') 

variable values will not be submitted due to single quotes around them. 

By using this type of query 

INSERT INTO mensajes (titulo, receptor, emisor, mensaje) VALUES ('{$titulo}','{$receptor}','{$emisor}','{$mensaje}')";

we ensure that variable values are getting properly submitted and query will be build

Comment: @juaqin123 ... what is in include("inc/setting.php");

Comment: @justrohu - his query is okay. It will still work. Now, back to the problem.

Comment: OP is using double quotes around `INSERT INTO` so php variables will be parsed, also, it will not fix error.

Comment: ok then what was the issue ... what are the contents of inc/setting.php file